# Angular RouterLink Open Hyperlink in New Window, Not Tabs

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routerlink, angular10

How do I open Angular routerLinks in New Windows, Not New Tabs?

```
<a  
  target="_blank"
  [routerLink]="['/product/',productData?.productId]"
>
```

This is not working in the latest Chrome per 2020 (still opening tabs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it using window.open method. Below is example for opening link in new window.

```
<a href="'/product/' + productData?.productId" target="popup" (click)="window.open('/product/' + productData?.productId,'name','width=600,height=400')">Open page in new window</a>
```

Check this website for reference. https://www.rapidtables.com/web/html/link/html-link-new-window.html

Answer (score 0):

```
<a onclick="window.open('/product/' + productData?.productId)"></a>
```